# In Javascript, can constants be shared between files, as in Ruby?

Tags: javascript

This is probably an odd question because it's more typical for people to ask how to *avoid* using globals.

Coming from the Ruby world, I've become very comfortable using globals in two specific examples:

1. Constants. When a file is imported in Ruby, all of its constants are automatically made available to the other files in the program.
2. (and this ties in with the first) Packages. When I load a Ruby Gem in a required file, it also becomes available in my other files.

I've been starting to use `module.exports`, but I'm finding that I'm importing same modules in lots of different files.

I'd really like to have these features in Javascript. The way I'm writing my code at the moment, I'm using a functional approach and passing all my constants as parameters. The problem is my code is getting too verbose for my liking.

I'm really not looking for a "short answer: no" type of response, here. Even if it is too difficult, I'd appreciate being pointed in a direction for how to avoid passing constants as parameters to functions.

Comment: Create a namespace object and add the properties you need, then include that file in each page you require them.

Comment: Short answer : Yes you can.

Comment: Will you be running this code server-side, client-side, or both?

Comment: @MikeC Server side for now, but ideally client side as well.

Comment: There's the [`global` object in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global). You can accomplish the same kind of thing in the browser by assigning variables to `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of using globals could be to use HTML5 Local Storage.

My thinking is, have an object with your globals, and on page load save each global variable into its own local storage location.

So you have an object with your globals stored:

```
var globals = {
    GLOBAL1: "SomeString",
    GLOBAL2: 400
}
```

Then `onload` / or if you want to do it sooner have it called before the page loads, you can have a function run through your globals and save the values into local storage

```
for(var key in globals) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, globals[key]);
}
```

Then, later on, when a function needs, for example `GLOBAL2` you can call:

```
localStorage.getItem("GLOBAL2");
```